# After sending sms android activity is Automatically moving to same Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i have created two activity pages. MainActivity and Proceed Activity. i was getting data from user in MainActivity page and through intent i was sendging to proceed activity.

Proceed page i was entering phone number then i was clicking send button. it was sending message successfully but after that i was creating start activity to move to mainactivity page. it is moving to main activity but after few seconds it is automatically coming to proceed activity.

1.In mainActivity i was sending list like

```
public void Proceed(View view){
        if(planetsList.size()==0){

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Add Product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;

        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Proceed.class);
        intent.putExtra("list_product", planetsList);
        Log.e("gjdgfl",Integer.toString(planetsList.size()));
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

2.in proceed page Coding is

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String no = mnumber.getText().toString();
                Float netTotal = 0.1f;

                ArrayList<Planet> myList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("list_product");

                Log.e("hai1",Integer.toString(myList.size()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               for (Planet temp : myList) {
                    sb.append(temp.getName()).append(" ").append(temp.getPerkg()).append("*").append(temp.getTotkg()).append("=").append(temp.getTotamt()).append("\n");
                   netTotal += temp.getTotamt();
                }
                sb.append("Total Amount is -"+netTotal);
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                System.out.println(no);
                String msg = sb.toString();

                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Proceed.class);
                PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,0);
                SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(no, null, msg, pi,null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Proceed.this);
                builder.setTitle("Confirmation");
                builder.setMessage("Message Sent Successfully")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                               Intent intent1 = new Intent(Proceed.this,MainActivity.class);
                                intent1.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
                                startActivity(intent1);

                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

}
```

Comment: Not sure but , may be something fishy here `Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Proceed.class);
                PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,0);
                SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(no, null, msg, pi,null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: above code is working for me. pls provide above answer as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `PendingIntent` class to `MainActivity`, it will redirect to MainActivity after sending sms.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,0);
SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
```

Comment: @Karthick Anbazhagan, Please see this answer, Raut Darpan has also edit his post after my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Read this :**

> If you give the foreign application an Intent, and that application
>   sends/broadcasts the Intent you gave, they will execute the Intent
>   with their own permissions. But if you instead give the foreign
>   application a PendingIntent you created using your own permission,
>   that application will execute the contained Intent using your
>   application's permission.

here is the problem :

> You are sending the intent as go to Proceed.class in Pending intent
>   thus when message is done it goes to Proceed.class

```
      Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Proceed.class);
                    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,0);
                    SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
```

Change this line :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: is there is any solution for this?

Comment: I have explained and pointed out the problem, now put debugging points and check the same

Comment: If this has helped you please accept the same, Regardds

Answer (score 1):

The Pending intent

```
 PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,0);
```

will wait for the event to occur and when messaging is done you are telling it to go to the Proceed class ( you gave it in the Intent)

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Proceed.class);
```

And after the messaging is done,The alert dialog will be shown and the Confirm button takes you to the MainActivity.
The problem here is the PendingIntent is still active and your application will still receive it until you cancel it or make sure you can use it only once.

1.Cancel a pending intent by

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Proceed.class);
 PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,0);
 alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmManager.cancel(pi);
```

2.Use a pending Intent only once by

```
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```